# Global Array kind of functionality in React functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React-dropzone-uploader

```
const [state,setState] = useState({document_blob_ids: [] })


const MyUploader = () => {
    
    const getUploadParams = ({ meta }) => {          // specify upload params and url for your files
      return { url: '/v1/file_uploads/' }
    }       
    const handleChangeStatus = ({ meta, file,xhr }, status) => {     // called every time a file's `status` changes
      console.log("handleStatus",status, meta, file) 
      if(status == "done") { 
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
        var arr_blob_ids = state.documents_blob_ids.slice()
        console.log("id added",json.blob.id)
        if (json.blob.id){
          arr_blob_ids.push(json.blob.id)
          setState({...state,documents_blob_ids: arr_blob_ids})
        }
       }

      else if(status == "removed") {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
        var arr_blob_ids = state.documents_blob_ids.slice()
        console.log("id removed",json.blob.id)
        if (json.blob.id){
          arr_blob_ids.filter( v => v!= json.blob.id)
          setState({...state,documents_blob_ids: arr_blob_ids})
        }       
      }
     
    }
        
    const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {   // receives array of files that are done uploading when submit button is clicked
      console.log(files.map(f => f.meta))
      allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove())
    }
  
    return (
      <Dropzone
        getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
        onChangeStatus={(handleChangeStatus}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        accept="image/*"    
        submitButtonContent = {null}
        SubmitButtonComponent = {null}    
      />
    )
  }
```

using the react-dropzone-uploader I'm trying to upload multiple files , But After a  Successful upload of file since i'm updating the state , the component is rerendering which makes the loss of preview of uploaded files..

So i'm looking for an alternate solution, like storing all the id's in a global array and on clicking the submit button I can update it to state.

can someone guide me how to declare and use global array or any other alternate solution that solves my problems..

Comment: You can't use react state ***outside*** of react components, but you can externally declare an array for use *within* the component. Note that updates to it will also fall *outside* react's scope so you will need to be more explicit with its usage and keeping it synced to your react component's state.

Comment: @DrewReese , How can i externally declare an array and use it inside function handleChangeStatus ??

Comment: It will be in the file scope. As long as it is declared in the same file as the component then anything in the component can reference it, just don't expect react to "react" to any updates to it.

Comment: you are saying : like declaring const arr = [ ] just below the state declaration , and i can use the arr in handleChangeStatus , But it isn't working///

Comment: More like, in lieu of the state statement; `const [state,setState] = useState({document_blob_ids: [] })` isn't valid outside the component `MyUploader`. Are you trying to temporarily store values in `arr_blob_ids` for use later within `handleChangeStatus`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes , i want to store them temporarily , and once user clicks on submit button , i can send them to backend  understood ??

Comment: Something like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/global-array-kind-of-functionality-in-react-functional-component-rgxkk)?